# Is having two wireless adapters with one disabled okay?

Tags: wireless-networking

I just got a new external wireless adapter for my desktop, and i currently have an internal one. Is it okay if i just disable the old one through the device manager then install the new one, or would they interfere with each other somehow?

Comment: If disabled in device manager it will not interfere with the new one.

Comment: You could open the desktop case and remove the old wireless card.

Comment: What are you specifically concerned with?  If the device is disabled it wouldn't be able to interfere, its not even on, its basically turned off.

Answer (score 1):

No problem should be expected.
You could even run them both at the same time.

Comment: Although running them both might create interferences depending on what canal they are.